# Kafka consumer was not able to poll

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-streams

If one kafka consumer application is reading message from kafka, another was not able to read and vice-versa.

We are running two independent applications, one will process message and another will read and put into a database.

Message which is been processing in first application is not available in the second application

Comment: What have you been tried so far ? Provide some code

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the code I can only guess ... :-)
I think that you have a topic with only one partition and both consumer applications are in the same consumer group. In this case only one consumer gets messages from the only one partition in the topic.
If you want both applications receiving messages from same topic, you need to put them into different consumer groups (group.id parameter for the consumer properties).